# Creating subplots 10m^2 using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to create a few subplots within my project, I don't really know how to do this in one layer I've tried creating polygons but that isn't really what I want I just want the boundary to outline the area I am focusing on. Is this possible?

Comment: Make a duplicate of your later > make a transparent fill

Comment: A boundary that outlines an area *is* a polygon, so why aren't polygons what you want?